# Get path of a Solution Item file in Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, add-in, vs-extensibility

I'm iterating through a solution and its projects and items and need to retrieve the path to the items on disk.

I can retrieve the project file name from `Project.FullName` and can get a project items path using `ProjectItem.Properites.Item("FullPath")`.

However, for an item in the solutions 'Solution Items' folder, the items Properties member is null and has no other properties which I can see could help me retrieve the path to the item.

Although by default it will be located in the same directory as the solution when it is added I can't rely on this assumption as it could be moved or added as a pre-existing item from another location.

Is there another way or something I'm missing to find the location of this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here, particuarly the "FileNames" property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx

Comment: Thanks, easy to miss these things with lots of apis to get something from differnt items :o/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fullPath = ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
```

I don't know why they don't start from 0